# F9 key does not work

Tags: nav, microsoft-dynamics

We use Microsoft Dynamics NAV 2009. When I press the <kbd>F9</kbd> key, I must see a sub-menu or other program options, but <kbd>F9</kbd> only mutes the sound of the PC. I disabled the Sound card of the PC, but it does not work.The others - <kbd>F5</kbd>, <kbd>F6</kbd>, <kbd>F7</kbd>, <kbd>F8</kbd> are working.Could it be an Registry issue? Can anyone help me?Thanks!

Comment: Hey @stani. This question is technically off topic on stack overflow as it's not strictly programming related. You can find more help (and post an on topic question) [here](http://superuser.com/) instead :)!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like another process has set the keyboard shortcut for <kbd>F9</kbd> already.
Most likely it will be a program which manages the sound mixer since it mutes your sound, so not your sound card itself.

Sadly it appears there is no simple way to find which program: [See here](https://superuser.com/questions/298484/is-there-any-way-to-get-a-list-of-the-system-wide-keyboard-shortcuts-currently-i)

I would first look into the programs which startup with your computer and see if there is software of your sound drivers that are running and stop those. Then restart NAV and see if the problem is solved...